# What's the standard way to use a PHP library?

Tags: php

Say I downloaded a PHP library (which I suppose usually comes as a bunch of `.php` files - is this correct?)

The only way I can think of using the library in my project is simply copy the files to my server and `include` or `require` them.

Is there a better or more standard way?

Also, how does `yum` relate to using PHP libraries?

Answer (score 2):

The most popular way of installing and using packages in php is using composer.  You can get more information on composer at https://getcomposer.org. Composer will handle the auto loading for you so that you don't need to include every single file into the files.

You may also be interested in having a look at [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) where you can find a bunch of packages to use with composer/your projects.

Comment: How is an arbitrary third party tool "standard"?

Comment: @Siguza, like it or not, Composer IS a standard nowadays.

Comment: @walther No, it is *popular*, not a standard. Something closer to a standard would be the PSR-* autoloaders.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, playing with words, aren't we? If you need to handle dependencies, you really don't have a choice. Either do it manually (who does this today anyway??) or use a tool (composer). When a tool becomes as widely used and popular (almost every single framework uses composer in one way or another), it becomes the standard. As long as someone doesn't come up with something better, of course.

Comment: That's exactly my point of view @walther. But as we're playing with words, I changed the answer to most popular instead of standard so that everybody is satisfied.

Comment: @walther It is quite trivial to manually implement a PSR autoloader and simply clone the projects that you need. Composer is essentially just a glorified autoloader with automated cloning of projects (I love Composer, but that is pretty much what it is).

Comment: The really nice thing about `composer` and the 'PSR' standards is that 'vendor' directory structures and namespaces became 'common'. So, it is easier to control the 'dependencies' manually. ;-/ I use an 'autoloader' utility.

Comment: But implementing a PSR autoloader is something 1/10 people who are using auto loading/dependency management do, composer is used by the rest of the ten. So how can you call PSR more standard??? @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: I see. How does yum relate to this?

Comment: yum is a package manager for openSUSE and has nothing to do with php autoloading. @AvivCohn. It's releated to it like apples and bananas are to each other.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, it's not only about including some files, but about managing dependencies. Part `with automated cloning of projects` is important here, because yes, you can implement an autoloader, but managing dependencies is a whole new topic. OP doesn't ask only about autoloading, but about using a 3rd party library. Composer makes sure you use the correct version and you don't have to do it manually. Your manual approach may work in small projects, but as it grows, it becomes really difficult to manage by hand.

Comment: @michael So when I want to use a PHP library in my code, yum has nothing to do with it? If so, than how *does* it relate to php?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Again yum is a package manager for openSUSE, not for php in any way. @AvivCohn

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, all you have to do is import the right files and that's all. There is no "standard" way to use 3rd party libraries I think.

But the library you are using should have documentation. Make sure to read it because maybe you only have to import one file and that file is importing the others.

Comment: I see. How does yum relate to this?

Comment: @AvivCohn, as michael already said, yum has nothing to do with it. YUM is a package manager for openSUSE (linux-based operating system), it has nothing to do with managing libraries in PHP.

Comment: As @walther said, yum doesn't relate to php libraries. As I know, yum has repos for php modules like mysqli, or pdo, etc... But not libraries.